# Get file server domain with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get plain domain without `http(s)://www.` (e.g. result of script is `example.com`) from the file link (`http://www.example.com/file.exe` or `https://example.com/folder/file.txt#someValue?params`).

How I can do it with js or jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with plain javascript.

```js
var url = new URL("https://example.com/folder/file.txt#someshit?someothershit");
var hostname = url.hostname.replace("www.", "");
console.log(hostname);
```

Comment: Note, `"www."` is part of `.hostname`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `URL()` constructor, `.hostname` property, replace `"www."` with empty string

```js
var url = new URL("http://www.example.com/file.exe")
          .hostname.replace(/www\./, "");
          
console.log(url);
```